# (LIBGDX) How can I incorporate, step by step, the accelerometer and use the Z axis on an ANDROID to move a car?

Tags: android, libgdx, accelerometer, tilt

I am trying to have the tilt of the Z axis in an Android phone power the movement of a Libgdx Box2D car.  I already know how to make the car move on my computer, but how do I implement that into an Android?  The orientation is LANDSCAPE.  Thanks so much!

I know something has to do with getRotation or something.... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the Accelerometer Readings like this:

```
float accelX = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
float accelY = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();
float accelZ = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerZ();
```

Wiki entry for more info:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Accelerometer

Then just apply a force to the body with it:

```
body.applyForceToCenter(<your_horizontal_accel_reading>, <vertical_if_needed_0_if_not>, true);
```

Comment: sorry, but how can I, for example, move a car when the device is tilted more than X degrees?